# Referring to css from a HTML page generated by a Python CGI script

Tags: html, css, python-2.7, tomcat7, cgi

About a week ago, I inherited a monitoring and notification tool which is written in Python. I am tasked with creating a proof of concept for a dashboard based on the data that the tool has collected over the years. Unfortunately, I am new to Python and have never done CGI programming - so a perfect mismatch. :) I am using tomcat7 because it is already installed in the machine.

The problem is that I am not able to get my generated HTML page to read the CSS file. My directory structure under `webapps/myapp` is as follows:

```
$ tree
  .
  ├── graphpages.css
  ├── index.html
  ├── META-INF
  │   └── context.xml
  └── WEB-INF
      ├── cgi
      │   ├── hello_world.cgi
      │   └── page1.cgi
      └── web.xml
```

I have tried to refer to the CSS in my HTML as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../graph_pages.css" />
```

Tried moving the file `graph_pages.css` under `WEB-INF/` and also by creating a directory `htdocs/` under `WEB-INF/` and placing the file inside that. Meaning:

```
$ tree
.
+-- index.html
+-- META-INF
¦   +-- context.xml
+-- WEB-INF
    +-- cgi
    ¦   +-- hello_world.cgi
    ¦   +-- page1.cgi
    +-- graphpages.css
    +-- web.xml
```

and

```
$ tree
.
+-- index.html
+-- META-INF
¦   +-- context.xml
+-- WEB-INF
    +-- cgi
    ¦   +-- hello_world.cgi
    ¦   +-- page1.cgi
    +-- htdocs
    ¦   +-- graphpages.css
    +-- web.xml
```

Of course, I updated the generated HTML too. But no help at all.

My browser is able to open the CSS file in the first directory structure above but not in the other two cases.

Please help me understand what the directory structure should be and how I can get the CSS to have an effect on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When having `graphpages.css` at the root level with `index.html` use the web root `/` as the starting point as opposed to a relative path `../`:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/graphpages.css" />`

Note: You have some references to `graphpages.css` and `graph_pages.css`. Please make sure you're consistent with the file name

Comment: That file name miss was a good catch. Thanks.
The name of the file was wrong. But changing it does not seem to fix the issue and modifying href does not seem to fix it. Please help.

Comment: make sure that when accessing myapp.com/graph_pages.css the css file pulls up.

Comment: Other things to try: chmod 755 graph_pages.css, make sure you have a html content type header in the cgi script

Comment: This is the portion till body tag starts:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head><title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/graph_pages.css" />
</head>


<body>

Comment: The file has 777 permissions. and I am able to access `myapp.com/graph_pages.css` directly from the browser

Comment: The content-type is as: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: Check apache logz, i saw somewhere that it may try to execute the css script in a py context as opposed to html. See if u find anything

Comment: Fixed!
@dwkd, the filename mismatch was part of the problem. Because of that, the server did not identify my css when it was in the right location and I was referring to it as `../graph_pages.css`.